# useState hook not working correctly with callback function in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-hooks

I am using iOS 17,Xcode 15, React version 18.2.0, and React Native version 0.72.7. In my React Native project, the useState hook doesn't seem to work correctly. I have a callback function, and inside the function when it triggers, I use setState to store the result. However, after the first useState setting, the callback is not functional. Everything works fine if I just comment out the useState variable.This issue only occurs on iOS; the code works fine on Android.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a React Native project.
- Create a component with a useState variable and a callback function.
- Trigger the callback function.
- Observe that the callback function is not functional after the first useState setting.

```
const [devices, setDevices] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('devices', devices);
  }, [devices]);


  const searchDevicesPress = (): void => {
    searchDevices(manager, (list) => {
      try {
 console.info('Triggered');
        setDevices(list);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  };

return  <Button onPress={searchDevicesPress} title="Search" />
```

To replicate the functionality of the searchDevice function, you can use the react-native-ble-plx library. This library provides a startDeviceScan() method that can be used to scan for nearby BLE devices. The startDeviceScan() method takes a callback function as an argument, which will be called whenever a new BLE device is discovered. The callback function will receive the device's information as an argument.

Comment: Are you seeing the log "triggered" in iOS

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code you have shared here. Are there any errors? What other debugging details can you provide? See if you can create a ***running*** [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Answer (score 0):

you are store state with object, but you setState by array `list`, first you need must decrale state again like this:

```
const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
```

Comment: OP doesn't say they have any issue with the initially undefined `devices` state value. Their problem is in the `searchDevicesPress` handler trying to enqueue a state update. I don't believe your answer here resolves anything.